# How to View "Broadcast"/ video call history logs from iPhone's decrypted data?

Tags: ios, iphone, github, open-source

Is there any way to view logs of my iphone being connected to sessions with the Waterbus app found on GitHub? Sort of like having call history logs but instead it's connection history with code details? We're trying to understand how this video-call app communicates with our devices.

Any repos, scripts or ways to fetch specific codecs names (RTMP, RTSP, etc.) also?

My coding mates and I have been trying out different scripts from Github. We've been using an open-source video chat to communicate: **[text](https://github.com/lambiengcode/waterbus)
**
For example, we like MVT's project for data decryption and analyzing iPhone backups:** [text](https://github.com/mvt-project/mvt)**

But we still can't find a way to locate video chat history from Waterbus..